# Refactor multiple overloaded methods using generics

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I have a class that contains several overloaded methods, such as:

```
interface SharedInterface
{
   public void commonMethod();
}

class Model1 implements SharedInterface
{
   public void commonMethod(){}
   public int foo(){ return 1; }
}

class Model2 implements SharedInterface
{
   public void commonMethod(){}
   public String bar(){ return "2"; }
}

class Client
{
   private ExternalClass external = new ExternalClass();

   public void handle( Model1 model )
   {
       external.calculate( model.foo() );
   }

   public void handle( Model2 model )
   {
       external.calculate( model.bar() );
   }
}
```

I want to make the Client class more generic so that it can handle any type of Model in the future. However, because each Model has its own specific public methods, the Client.handle() method needs to change its behaviour according to the given Model. For example, if a Model1 instance is given, then call the method foo() of that model; if a Model2 instance is given, then call the method bar(), etc. In the future more types of models will be created. The following solution breaks the open closed principle and seems like a very bad practice:

```
class Client
{
   private ExternalClass external = new ExternalClass();

   public void handle( SharedInterface model )
   {
       if( model instanceof Model1 )
          external.calculate( model.foo() );
       else if( model instanceof Model2 )
          external.calculate( model.bar() );
   }
}
```

I am thinking of using Generics but I am not sure how generics could solve this.

Please note that the Client class has dependencies (makes use of libraries). The Models have to be POJOs without any dependencies to any other class. Therefore, because of the fact that the implementation of Client.handle() makes use of these dependencies, the method cannot be moved inside the Model classes.

Could someone please provide some alternatives?

Comment: I don't think you need generics for this. Don't you just need a `handle` method in `SharedInterface`?

Comment: You are correct @Paul Boddington. I was not clear about my use case. I updated my description to make my use case clearer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Visitor design pattern best suits your problem... Link can help you out
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor..

Comment: I believe the Visitor Pattern also works in this situation

Comment: Adapter pattern is to useful when we need two incompatible work together where as in visitor pattern we are focusing on separation of concerns. 
As mentioned above Model1 & Model2 have different operational behaviors also.

Comment: Adapter pattern could work if there is a common denominator that you can convert your models to. If this is not true, I would be for Visitor pattern, which is actually rather close to the example in the question.

Comment: @Clashsoft/ @Mifeet : Thanks for your valuable comments. I go through both the design patterns again and found that you guys are very right. I feel i am having a bit misconception. Updating my answer. Thanks once again and very sorry for my wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your handling logic is different for each type and the different behavior has to be described somewhere, for each `Model` you add, you have to have a piece of handling logic, this is a perfect case for *overloading* -- which you already do in your first code bit.

If you're dead set on keeping `Client` clear of those implementations. You can define the different handling logic in wrappers (adapters) for your data POJOs and pass those to `handle()`, e.g.:

```
class Client {
    private ExternalClass external = new ExternalClass();

    public void handle(PojoAdapter<?> model) {
        model.getExecuted(external);
    }
}

// Actually, generics are not necessary here, just to
// avoid declaring the same model field with different type
// in each implementation
abstract class PojoAdapter<T extends SharedInterface> {
    protected T model;
    public PojoAdapter(T model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public abstract void getExecuted(ExternalClass excls);
}

class Model1Adapter extends PojoAdapter<Model1> {
    @Override public void getExecuted(ExternalClass excls) {
        external.calculate(model.foo());
    }
}

class Model2Adapter extends PojoAdapter<Model2>{
    @Override public void getExecuted(ExternalClass excls) {
        external.calculate(model.bar());
    }
}
```